# Dividing two extremely large numbers represented as a linked list of unsigned long longs

Tags: c, linked-list, division, largenumber

I am working in c and as said in the title, I have a `struct` that is a node for a doubly linked list of `unsigned long longs` that represent extremely large numbers.

I need to implement basic arithmetic on them and have accomplished `+`,`-`,`*` but I still need division. I have seen answers for arithmetic on large numbers represented as linked lists but my problem has another part, overflow.

I am currently trying long division and my problem is that when the first digit(`unsigned long long`) does not evenly divide then there is the remainder which gets carried into a two digit(two `unsigned long long`s) number. I do not know how to divide a large number represented as two `ull`s by a `ull` while keeping precision. The division function will only ever be called on two numbers where the second divides the first evenly.

Not sure what other info I need to give but I am stuck here and any intuition would help, thanks.

Edit: I apologize for my apparent newness to StackOverflow but for those curious the way I ended up solving the problem was by treating the numbers as binary and doing division bit by bit. This solution eliminates the problems I had.

Comment: Integer division? Do long division until you manage to get something else.

Comment: 1) C is not C++ is not C. 2) Edit line 4704451311, crystal ball says there are all your problems. If there is no such line, you might want to read [ask] and post a [mcve].

Comment: The info you need to give is the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows what you have tried.

Comment: Donald Knuth discussed division in detail in his The Art of Computer Programming. I forget which book of the series, probably II. That said, you can make a rough working but inefficient division op by using Newton-Raphson search (or simply binary search, which is even slower).

Comment: You are not clear whether the divisor is also a linked list large number, or a simple integer type. Large number arithmetic is easier if the storage type and multiplier / divisor are smaller than the max type the implementation can handle. For example if the max integer is 64-bit, then you work with 32 bit, so that you can handle overflow and carry, etc.

Comment: Your question is quite abstract without an example. It doesn't have to be much. Just enough to represent the problem.

Comment: Follow Aganju's suggestion and part both(!) dividend and divisor into longs (just half them, can be done fast with bitshifting but costs 2n memory) and do a normal long division with e.g.: Knuth, TAoCP II, 4.3.1, algorithm D (p. 285 in my book). This algorithm is also well suited for exact division, as in your case. See question 40 (answer ibid. p. 629).

Comment: Hello  @Geral Collom "treating the numbers as binary and doing division bit by bi"t. Some Docs to try this solution Please?. Thanks.  Or maybe Help me with code?. I will translate to Java. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution might be - considering what you already *have* - to do all divisions in two steps. Basically you act as if your *long long unsigned ints* are only *long unsigned ints*.

This doubles the length of the chain you have to work through, and quadruples the number of operations needed, but if this is not a concern, you can then do the division of the remainder of lu plus the next lu inside a llu, which again gives you a remainder of less than an lu.

In other words, as you need something larger than llu but there is nothing, do your whole work with lu, and then there *is* something larger for this operation available - the *llu*.